# Idea or tool for distribution of power force (people) geographically

Tags: google-maps, geolocation, maps, geocoding, geospatial

I have a lot of places with coordinates, I have people that maintain those places when something goes wrong.
I'm looking for a way to place the field people so they be the closest possible to the major amount of sites.

The idea is something like:
I have 3000 sites with lat&long.
I want to choose how many people I have available and with that info I want to get the optimum coordinates to distribute them.

I'm not looking for a existent tool (but if exists I could look for it), but I dont know how to start with something like this (I can work with mysql, php, Gmaps, I learn another languaje/tool if it helps me).
Thank you

Comment: Hey I think that I have tool that could help you out.
We could handle the coordinates in a way that you can use them
http://www.pinntag.com

Comment: I don't know if that solve my problem, i have 3000 coordinates, I can map them in gmaps...but I need the optimum location (distribution) of n employees so they cover the maximum number of locations (or be closer to the máximum number of sites possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem of distributing an arbitrary number of people upon a given set of locations is an [optimization](https://www.google.hr/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&cad=rja&ved=0CCsQFjAA&url=http%3A%2F%2Fen.wikipedia.org%2Fwiki%2FDynamic_programming&ei=stcxUabfF8iG4gSI24FA&usg=AFQjCNHkBaimkGt6WXZrWjUdW_EtduGEZQ&sig2=B6F4Q4vHHKAptffEnz1aSA&bvm=bv.43148975,d.bGE) problem. More specifically, it can be interpreted as a [clustering](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cluster_analysis) problem. A nice clustering example implemented in JS can be found at the [A Curious Animal](http://acuriousanimal.com/code/animatedCluster/) blog.

As you can see in the above example, *clustering* means grouping of neighbouring locations. In other words, it is a computation that yields an optimal distribution of groups of locations (clusters) upon a given set of locations. If we declare that *a cluster* is *a person* instead of *a location group* we get to your problem statement.

Since the number of people is your input, I'd suggest k-means clustering algorithm ([short explanation](http://www.improvedoutcomes.com/docs/WebSiteDocs/Clustering/K-Means_Clustering_Overview.htm), [available software list @wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-means_algorithm#Software)).

EDIT:

When working with optimization algorithms in general there are two caveats:

- the chosen algorithm is designed to solve your (class of) problem
- some input parameter combination can lead to odd, non acceptable results

The first point requires some knowledge of the algorithm, while the second is a matter of try-and-error as you nicely noticed. Also, the suptile differences in input can result in huge differences in output.

The above link states that the k-means algorithm "does not work well with [non-globuar clusters](http://www.improvedoutcomes.com/docs/WebSiteDocs/Glossary/Glossary_of_Terms_Acronym_List.htm#N_Index)".

It will be easier to start from his opposite - a [globular cluster](http://www.improvedoutcomes.com/docs/WebSiteDocs/Glossary/Glossary_of_Terms_Acronym_List.htm#G_Index) which is defined as: "A more precise mathematical term is [convex](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convex_set), which roughly means that any line you can draw between two cluster members stays inside the boundaries of the cluster.":

[image: convex set]

A non-globular cluster (non-convex set of points) looks like this:

[image: non convex set]

Probably your "thin ovoid clusters" are non-convex?

Another important characteristic (also stated in the above link) is that k-means is a [non-deterministic](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nondeterministic_algorithm) algorithm, meaning that it may (and most probably will) yield different outputs for the same input when ran multiple times.

This happens because the algorithm makes the initial partitioning of clusters at random - and the final output is highly sensitive of that initial partitioning. Depending on the implementation used, you may have some space for modifying here.

If that doesn't lead to satisfying results the only thing left is to try another algorithm (since the locations are given). I'll suggest [QT clustering algorithm](https://sites.google.com/site/dataclusteringalgorithms/quality-threshold-clustering-algorithm-1) that I use in a commercial product. It is a deterministic clustering algorithm which takes as input the minimal cluster size, and the threshold distance - distance of the point from the center of the cluster.

But, with this approach you will need to modify the algorithm itself. The algorithm usually stops when "no more clusters can be formed having the minimum cluster size.". You'll need to modify the algorithm to stop when a wanted amount of clusters has been reached. The minimum cluster size value should be OK as 1, but you might want to try out different values for the threshold distance.

Here is some [code sample in C#](https://rtmath.net/help/html/1f8505a3-3f68-4b17-9fe8-201208d753fc.htm) that I stumbled upon. Hope it was helpful.

Comment: thank you @linski yesterday I tryed kmeans with Weka using lat,long,name for each site and defining the number of clusters I need.
I liked the results, there are some strange clusters (in shape when I map them), maybe shapes closer to squares/circles are better than a thin and ovoid groups (the center is far from 2 parts), but I have to analyze them better, I think this is a matter of try and error now. Any other suggestion will be well received.

Comment: u r welcome, I apologize for the late answer.

Comment: I think I will stick with k-means, they are convex but sometimes there are big distances between the longest side of the ovoid. But I thik I can live with that, I will try running kmeans again with same data to see the possible changes and maybe try QT to see what happends. Thanks again.